# java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Wed Jan 11 00:00:00 CET 2012"

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

I have the next problem with this date:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Wed Jan 11 00:00:00 CET 2012"
```

I have this:

```
 DateFormat formatter ; 
      Date dateIn=null;  
       formatter = new SimpleDateFormat( "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy" ); 
       try {
        dateIn = (Date)formatter.parse(dateI);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

What I'm doing bad?. Thanks

Comment: Timezone is missing in format.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use timezone and also a locale

```
SimpleDateFormat( "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.US);
```

to reflect English language in the input string (days and month names).

Answer (score 3):

You need to add `z` in your format string for including timezone. Try this:

`SimpleDateFormat( "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy" );`

Comment: I have tryed this and nothing the same mistake, what can I do?

Comment: I don't know, I'm going to try to clean the whole project