# Date with CET: Unparseable date

Tags: java, android, parsing, date

Sorry for opening yet another Date-parsing topic, but I give up...

the code:

```
SimpleDateFormat SDF_FROM = new SimpleDateFormat( "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssz" );
SDF_FROM.parse( "2015-02-01T11:58:34CET" )
```

throws

> java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2015-02-01T12:30:47CET" (at offset 19)

I tried to run the same code in groovy (just for testing), and it works fine.

What am I missing?
TIA

Comment: possible duplicate of [java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Wed Jan 11 00:00:00 CET 2012"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13026162/java-text-parseexception-unparseable-date-wed-jan-11-000000-cet-2012)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to add the locale to the SimpleDateFormat constructor:

```
SimpleDateFormat SDF_FROM = new SimpleDateFormat( "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssz", Locale.UK );
```

Comment: ty, seems to be working! can you elaborate a bit? I was using the `Locale.DE` as default on the device. Why wasn't it sufficient to parse `CET`?

Comment: The Strings for timezone depends on the Locale. for Locale.DE `CET` will be written as `MEZ`. Is it enought explanation?